# How to create a plot using instead of 8760 hours 365 days and 52 weeks in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am new to Python and am having trouble with a small task. I have a time series with 8760 hours and certain values. I have already split the course of the values for one year. But now I want to plot the course of the values both weekly and daily. Can you help me with this? I would be very grateful

```
| timestep |   value  |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1        |    …     |
| 2
  …
| 8760     |    …     |
```

Comment: Can you show me the code how you plot over the course of the year?

Comment: groupby 24 rows for day, and 24 x 7 rows for week?

Comment: Sure. 
`plot = sns.lineplot(                               x = 'timestep',                                       y = 'B',                                               data = df                                               ) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new dataframe by calculate the average of the hours. For example, daily will be 24 hours.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = "" #Your path
df = pd.read_csv (path+"data.csv")

daily=df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//24).mean()

plt.plot(daily['timestep'],daily['value'])
plt.show()
```

For weekly, just change 24 to 24*7.